# How to write a loop so that I will draw to user canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas element. I have a few troubles, how to draw to user canvas in "realtime",.. So, that my drawing is not already there when they open the site, but rather to draw to the canvas like somebody is actually drawing... So looping through the coordinates.

That's what I tried so far but it's BAAD! It's drawing slowly and it takes a lot of CPU.

```
    // Pencil Points
var ppts = [];

/* Drawing on Paint App */

tmp_ctx.lineWidth = 4;
tmp_ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
tmp_ctx.lineCap = 'round';
tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = '#4684F6';
tmp_ctx.fillStyle = '#4684F6';

// Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
tmp_ctx.beginPath();

var timer = 0;

$.timer(500, function() {
    ppts.push({x: 10*timer, y: 5*timer});
    timer++;
})

$.timer(10, function() {
    if (timer > 250) {
        timer = 0;
        clearTempCanvas();
    } else {

        for (var i = 1; i < ppts.length - 2; i++) {
            var c = (ppts[i].x + ppts[i + 1].x) / 2;
            var d = (ppts[i].y + ppts[i + 1].y) / 2;

            tmp_ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ppts[i].x, ppts[i].y, c, d);
        }

        console.log(i);


        tmp_ctx.stroke();
    }
})

function clearTempCanvas() {
    // Writing down to real canvas now
    ctx.drawImage(tmp_canvas, 0, 0);
    // Clearing tmp canvas
    tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
    // Emptying up Pencil Points
    ppts = [];  
}
```

Comment: So basically you want an animated drawing on canvas when the user views it?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK, yeah that's it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for you to learn from:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/j4HWS/

It works like this:

- define some points to animate along and put those points in an array points.push({x:25,y:50})
- use requestAnimationFrame to create an animation loop
- break each line segment into 100 sub-segments and animate along those sub-segments

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle="blue";

        var points=[];
        points.push({x:125,y:125});
        points.push({x:250,y:200});
        points.push({x:125,y:200});
        points.push({x:125,y:125});
        var pointIndex=1;
        var linePct=0;
        var continueAnimating=true;

        var img=new Image();img.onload=start;
        img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/pen.png";
        function start(){
            animate();
        }

        function draw(pointIndex,linePct){

            // clear the canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            // draw fully completed lines
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
            for(var i=1;i<pointIndex;i++){
                ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
            }

            // draw current line-in-process
            var pos=getLineXYatPercent(points[pointIndex-1],points[pointIndex],linePct/100);
            ctx.lineTo(pos.x,pos.y);
            ctx.stroke();

            // draw the pen
            ctx.drawImage(img,pos.x-93,pos.y-92);
        }

        function animate() {

            if(!continueAnimating){return;}

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            // Drawing code goes here
            draw(pointIndex,linePct);

            if(++linePct>100){
                linePct=1;
                if(++pointIndex>points.length-1){
                    continueAnimating=false;
                }
            }
        }


        function getLineXYatPercent(startPt,endPt,percent) {
            var dx = endPt.x-startPt.x;
            var dy = endPt.y-startPt.y;
            var X = startPt.x + dx*percent;
            var Y = startPt.y + dy*percent;
            return( {x:X,y:Y} );
        }        

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No :(
Beat me to it.
Leave easy question for us noobs :P

Comment: lol no,its fine. :)
Bring back the answer, the guy must be brainstorming his ass off.